# Server has failed to start

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat7

I have different eclipse versions and in every version the server(Tomcat v6) starts without a problem. For one version I get this errors:

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.eclipse.stardust.ide.wst.server.tomcat.EmbeddedDerbyLifecycleListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:205)
    ...
28.02.2014 10:20:51 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SCHWERWIEGEND: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

I wonder what is the reason for this when the server runs in my other eclipse without a problem.

Eclipse Version: Kepler SR1

Comment: which version of eclipse ? what is machine architecture 64-bit or 32-bit ?

Comment: it seems you didn't configured your tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I copied the server.xml file from my direction where i installed tomcat to server directory in eclipse. So there it is replaced and now it goes well. I don't know the orgin of the error. Maybe the server.xml file was damaged

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" exception might be the library path has not been configured properly. Check if environment variables such as "JAVA_HOME", "CATALINA_HOME", "CATALINA_BASE", "CLASSPATH" are configured correctly.

Better run bin/version.sh script under tomcat installation to see if all environment variables are set properly. Generally you have to get some thing like below.

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.50/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
Server built:   Dec 19 2013 10:18:12
Server number:  7.0.50.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.2.0-4-686-pae
Architecture:   i386
JVM Version:    1.6.0_27-b27
JVM Vendor:     Sun Microsystems Inc.
```