# Eclipse + Tomcat 7 + Audit Trial DataSource - Server Failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to create stardust application.

When I configure tomcat server and Audit Trial DataSource (using documentation http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst/html/wst-integration/configuration.html?cp=60_7_4_2) and start server I get:

```
lis 20, 2014 10:15:54 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.stardust.ide.wst.server.tomcat.EmbeddedDerbyLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)...
```

I use Eclipse Luna, Tomcat 7, java 8 and ArchLinux.
I've installed all Eclipse Process Manager plugins.

What could cause that problem ?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091792/server-has-failed-to-start

Comment: None of these anwsers work. Anwser posted by LittleProgrammer is wrong because it just disables Audit Trial DataSource and i need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from java 8 to java 7 and now it works.